# Buttons with semi circular ends

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to obtain buttons with semi circular ends.

If I change the border to any of the rounded options using the theme editor various degrees of rounding are obtain however the buttons increase in height to twice or more.

Is it possible to achieve normal sized buttons with semi circular ends without having to create a custom component?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention if you are trying to use Round Border, Round Rect Border or image border so I did this with both. I customized colors a bit so this will be obvious but other than that everything should work fine.

[image: End Result]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shai.. round border is precisely what was required once the rectangle checkbox was ticked.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including code and this is probably a duplicate question so your answer is going to get downvoted BUT Here is an example of how borders can be rounded with CSS.

p.s that tag does not exist.

```css
.button{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:.25em .5em;
  
  /* this rounds corners */
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to reply however there is no code included since it specifically relates to using the CodenameOne designer's theme support which does not generally require using code.

Comment: My mistake. I assumed this forum was all programming-related.